# Personal Supplications in Native Language

Tags: tefilla

We're allowed to add personal supplications within the Amidah during either Shema Koleinu or after Elokai Netzor. My question surrounding this: is one allowed to make these supplications in their native language (English, spanish , etc) or if since it is in the middle of tefilah it also should be in hebrew - so as not to cause some sort of interruption?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) AYBA and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 3):

The Shulchan Aruch cites different opinions about adding supplications during Shmoneh Esrei in ones native language in Siman 101:4. Mishna Brurah (122 s.k. 8) implies that you can, though its preferable to add supplications (in any language, including Hebrew) after Elokai Ntzor:

> כתב הח"א נכון וראוי לכל אדם להתפלל בכל יום ביחוד על צרכיו ופרנסתו ושלא ימוש התורה מפיו וזרעו וזרע זרעו ושיהיו כל יוצאי חלציו עובדי ה' באמת ושלא ימצא ח"ו פסול בזרעו וכל מה שיודע בלבו שצריך לו ואם אינו יודע לדבר צחות בלשה"ק יאמרנה אף בלשון אשכנז רק שיהיה מקירות לבו. וטוב יותר לקבוע תפלות על כל הענינים הצריכים לו אחר שסיים כל הי"ח מלקבעם בברכת שומע תפלה כדי שכשיצטרך לענות קדיש או קדושה יהיה יוכל לענות אחר אמירתו יהיו לרצון לכו"ע

Comment: The reason given by the Mishnah Berurah for saying it after Elokai Netzor is not because it is in another language. He states that it is so one will be able to answer to Kaddish and kedushah, and that applies even to a supplication in Hebrew.

Comment: @shmu I never said the reason for saying it after Elokai Netzor is because it is in another language, but I will edit it anyway in case others misunderstand it as you did

Answer (score 1):

The Amidah itself may be recited, if necessary, in one's native language. So after Elokai netzor, it surely should be permitted.

כבר המשנה בסוטה (לב.) מעוררת נושא זה:

> "אלו נאמרין בכל לשון: פרשת סוטה, ווידוי מעשר, **קרית שמע ותפלה וברכת המזון**[1], ושבועת העדות ושבועת הפיקדון. ואלו נאמרין בלשון הקודש: מקרא ביכורים, וחליצה, ברכות וקללות, ברכת כהנים, וברכת כהן גדול, ופרשת המלך, ופרשת עגלה ערופה, ומשוח מלחמה בשעה שמדבר אל העם"
>
> These are recited in any language, not specifically Hebrew: The portion of the warning and the oath administered by the priest to a woman suspected by her husband of having been unfaithful [sota]; and the declaration of tithes, which occurs after the third and the sixth years of the seven-year Sabbatical cycle, when one declares that he has given his tithes appropriately; **Shema; and the Amida prayer; and Grace after Meals;** and an oath of testimony, where one takes an oath that he does not have any testimony to provide on a given issue; and an oath on a deposit, where one takes an oath that he does not have possession of another’s deposit.